# Render pdf page preview in html with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I want to generate some pdf page previews from a pdf in a html page. Those previews are generated correctly but not in the same order as pdf`s pages.

My code is :

```
 var PDF_FILES_DIRECTORY = "",
            PDF_FILES = ['pdf2.pdf'];
    var CURRENT_FILE = {};
    $.each(PDF_FILES, function (index, pdf_file) {
        PDFJS.getDocument(PDF_FILES_DIRECTORY + pdf_file).then(function (pdf) {
            for(idxPage = 1 ; idxPage < pdf.numPages ; idxPage++) {
                pdf.getPage(idxPage).then(function (page) {
                    var viewport = page.getViewport(1);
                    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: ctx,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };

                    page.render(renderContext).then(function () {
                        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        var img_src = canvas.toDataURL();
                        var $img = $("<img>").attr("src", img_src);
                        var $thumb = $("<div>")
                                .attr("class", "thumb")
                                .append($img);

                        $thumb.appendTo("#thumbnail");
                        canvas.remove();
                    });
                }); // end of getPage
            }
        }); // end of getDocument
}); // end of each
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would imagine because there are two asynchronous processes going on.  page.render() from page 2 could finish before page 1.  You will likely have to add some sort of ordering to the thumbnails you are appending.